# Receive an error when trying to run yarn codegen using the graph to generate types for contract ABIs

Tags: blockchain, the-graph

Hello Team I Receive the Following Error when using the Graph `yarn codegen` command trying to generate types for contract ABIs

**× Failed to generate types for contract ABIs: Failed to generate types for contract ABI: Conversion from 'AssemblyScript' to 'ethereum' for source type 'MyStruct' is not supported**

has anyone ever encountered this before?

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get the issue resolved using

`yarn add @graphprotocol/graph-cli@0.29.0`

however downgrading to the following resolves the issue

`yarn add @graphprotocol/graph-cli@0.26.0`

I hope this can help someone else

Thank You Team